# I can't get jQuery to work

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to try out some jQuery and having no luck at all. Was writing code and what not and nothing was working. So I tried some JQuery from w3schools and that didn't even work.
Any idea why I cant get it to work?

I have this in the head of my html

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Still doesn't work.

Grateful for any help Thanks
Mikey

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("#div1").fadeIn();
$("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
$("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
<br><br>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div>        <br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;">    </div><br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;">  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Copied that into notepad, saved it then ran it in chrome, when I pressed the button nothing happened.

Thank you to everyone who help

Comment: We need a more complete example. There's nothing wrong per se in this one line of code.

Comment: "doesn't work"? jQuery is a library, not something that auto-runs. You need something written _using jquery_ as well. (Like having a bike but no rider and saying the bike doesn't work).

Comment: What did u try? Paste the code

Comment: The script provided just inserts the jQuery library into the document. Where are you using jQuery?

Comment: First: http://w3fools.com/ Second: Show your code which does not work. Otherwise it is hard to say something. Code you shown to us simply attach jquery to your web page. It do nothing itself.

Comment: @Mikey [your code works fine here...](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/3UZ8y/)

Comment: @Neal you beat me by [19 seconds](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/sRhdW/1/).. but my fiddle is better :P uses jsFiddle as it is meant to be used :P

Comment: @rlemon haha that is what happens when you try to separate out the OPs code :-P

Comment: @rlemon [now it is tidy ^_^](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/sRhdW/2/)

Comment: @Neal ye I know, but doesn't work when I open it in chrome.

Comment: @Mikey It works in Chrome - it does not work with relative urls in a local environment (not behind a webserver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is the scheme relative url that you are using to load jQuery. Since I assume you are loading the html file locally, your page's scheme is `file://`. When you go to load jQuery using `//` as the source it is looking on your local filesystem for a folder called `ajax.googleapis.com`. Replace `//` in your script tag with `https://` to solve your problem.

Comment: OR, set up a simple webserver locally and run from `localhost`

Answer (score 4):

jQuery can't be found with this code if you simply paste it in Notepad, save it and open the file in a browser.

You must either :

- serve your file using an HTTP server (i.e. not access it using `file://`)
- or change the URL of jQuery to not use a [protocol relative URL](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) (an URL starting with `//`)

The simplest fix would be to change

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

but the serious one will be to always test using a local HTTP server (it's very easy to install Apache on any OS including Windows). There are many things you can't test with `file://`, including most cross domain ajax operations.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Problem is that `//ajax.googleapis.com` is used to avoid problems with different protocols (http/https). Browser will add protocol used for a page. When you open your HTML from a file on your hard drive, file:// protocol is used. And browser tries to load jquery using `file://ajax.googleapis.com`, but that will not work because you have no folder `ajax.googleapis.com` on your hard drive. So, simply specify protocol for jquery explicitly

Comment: `-2` until you give a reason why.

Comment: And now you are all better ^_^

Comment: @Neal Ha) Never seen an effect like this on SO ) While adding explanation to an answer - two down votes ))